# .py list won't populate a spinner value in a .kv file using kivy/python

Tags: python, kivy, spinner

I'm completely stumped. I am populating a value attribute in a .kv file with a list from a .py file.

.kv file

```
                Spinner:
                    id: Mix_ingredient_1_spiner
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: 200, 30
                    background_normal : ''
                    background_color: [.6549, 1, 1, 1]
                    text: "pick your ingredient"
                    values: root.i_list
                    on_text: root.print_Ingredient_list()
                    on_press:root.print_Ingredient_list()
```

the .py file

```
class Product_1_Mix(Screen):
    i_list =  copy.deepcopy(config.ingredient_name_list)
    # i_list = ["eggs", "milk", "flour", "sugar", "bad Chocolate"]
    def print_Ingredient_list(self):
        Product_1_Mix.i_list =  copy.deepcopy(config.ingredient_name_list)
        print(config.ingredient_name_list)
        print(Product_1_Mix.i_list)
```

When I uncomment the i_list and hard code the list is populates fine.  When I use the i_list set to the list in the config file there is nothing in the list.

I use root.print_Ingredient_list() to debug, using the config list to populate the spinner value I get this:

['Milk', 'Sugar', 'Flour', 'Apples', 'Carmel', 'Chocolate']
['Milk', 'Sugar', 'Flour', 'Apples', 'Carmel', 'Chocolate']

Which is the correct list from the config file.  *This shows that i_list is taking the values from the config file list correctly.*  but it is not populating the spinner.

What's going on?!?

When I only set i_list outside def print_Ingredient_list(self): I get this:

['Milk', 'Sugar', 'Flour', 'Apples', 'Carmel', 'Chocolate']
[]

Comment: Your `print_Ingredient_list` sets the `i_list` again and then prints it. Better comment out this second assignment. And the function is probably called at a time after the class `Product_1_Mix` is created Something may have changed between class creation and function call.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion,  Just prints a blank list after I comment it out.  Working on the second part of you comment now.  Thanks.  When I set i_list like thsi: i_list = ["eggs", "milk", "flour", "sugar", "bad Chocolate"] and do or do nit call the function it populates just fine.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: As `print_Ingredient_list` doesn't need `self` you can make it a `staticmethod` and call it directly after the class definition.

Comment: Try changing `i_list` to a `ListProperty`.

Comment: I've tried to change to a ListProperty and searched on how to do it.  Either it doesn't work or I am not doing it right.  i_list =  ListProperty(config.ingredient_name_list).  Tried other ways as well but they crashed the code

Comment: This worked: class Product_1_Mix(Screen):
    # i_list =  ListProperty(config.ingredient_name_list)
    i_list =  []
    # i_list = ["eggs", "milk", "flour", "sugar", "bad Chocolate"]
    def print_Ingredient_list(self):
        print(Product_1_Mix.i_list)
        Product_1_Mix.i_list =  copy.deepcopy(config.ingredient_name_list)
        print(config.ingredient_name_list)
        print(Product_1_Mix.i_list)
        self.ids.Mix_ingredient_1_spiner.values = Product_1_Mix.i_list

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
class Product_1_Mix(Screen):
# i_list =  ListProperty(config.ingredient_name_list)
i_list =  []
# i_list = ["eggs", "milk", "flour", "sugar", "bad Chocolate"]
def print_Ingredient_list(self):
    print(Product_1_Mix.i_list)
    Product_1_Mix.i_list =  copy.deepcopy(config.ingredient_name_list)
    print(config.ingredient_name_list)
    print(Product_1_Mix.i_list)
    self.ids.Mix_ingredient_1_spiner.values = Product_1_Mix.i_list
```